# what does this expression do? (django)

Tags: django

What does this expression do? (Django)

```
some_result = ( queryset1 | queryset2 )
```

I mean the expression between braces.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its an **OR** operation usually use with the **Q** object

Here [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects)